# can we group by day of the week using hibernate?

Tags: group-by, hql, dayofweek

I want the query results to be grouped by day of the week .. like into 7 groups Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... etc one for each

the column in the table is a timestamp field like 12-Mar-2011 .....
so I don't care which dates exist in the table I just need to get 7 groupings and if there is a count column which doesnt exist for like thursday it should return 0 and for wednesday the count should the total counts for all wednesday and like wise for each day of the week.

How do I mplement this query with HQL/criteria?

Is there a built in clause like this that I can use in Hibernate (HQL/Criteria)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
select dayofweek(dateField), count(*)
from PersistentClass
group by 1
```

Comment: there´s no such function, only if you create a custom function to fit your dialect.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try 'order by' clause?

Smth like this:

```
FROM tableName as table
ORDER BY table.dayOfWeek ASC
```

In what form you store your data?

Comment: I have a date column in the table, its not a dayOfWeek column, how do I group by (date.day_of_week) ?... Thanks