# Howto GroupBy Day/Week /Year using GORM?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have a need in which i have to return a count related to a day/week or year.

Example:
Assume i have orders which are placed on a certain date

```
class Order {
    Date orderDate
}
```

How would i get an overview of the amount of orders per day / per week / per year etc?

Comment: You can try HQL and date functions as suggested here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222370/can-we-group-by-day-of-the-week-using-hibernate/11461009#11461009

Answer (score 0):

It's untested but you need something like this:

```
class Order {
    Date orderDate
    BigDecimal amount
    static namedQueries = {
        summaryProojectionByDate = {
            projections {
                count("id", "orderCount")
                sum("amount", "amountSum")
                groupProperty("orderDate", "orderDate")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This groups by a specific date. I think it would be hard to group by weeks in HQL.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon [this blog](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2012/11/08/create-game-leaderboard-using-sqlprojection/) that suggests using the new sqlProjection for Grails 2.0 and also has alternative solutions for Grails 1.x.