# Extract day of week (i.e. 'saturday') from date field - HQL

Tags: sql, date, hql, extract

I have a date field in a hive table  following this format:

```
'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

I'm looking for a function (let's call this yet-to-be-discovered-by-me function **dayofweek()**)  that will return '*friday*' when run on today's date. So, to be explicitly clear, this query:

```
SELECT DAYOFWEEK(DT.ds), DT.ds
FROM dateTable DT
WHERE DT.ds = '2014-11-14'
LIMIT 1
```

would return this value:

```
'friday'   '2014-11-14'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) google searching as of yet unfruitful.

Clark

P.S. The response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222370/can-we-group-by-day-of-the-week-using-hibernate) did not work for me...error returned: '`Invalid function 'dayofweek''`

Comment: the following URL has a list of hive operators - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

Comment: Do not mind calculating the day of week somehow, but can't conceive of a reasonably simple way to do so.

Comment: Have you tried DATENAME(DW,DT.ds) ?

Answer (score 0):

Should you care for an equation, following is C code hopefully simple enough to translate into SQL.

Important to use integer math.

```
#define MARCH 3
int dow_Sunday0(int year, int month, int day) {
  if (month < MARCH) {
    month += 12;
    year--;
  }
  // Add days for each year and leap years 
  day += year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400;
  // add days for the month
  day += month*30 + ((month-MARCH)*39 + 25)/64;
  // modulo 7
  return (day+3)%7;
}
```

This works for valid [Gregorian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DAYNAME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function, like this:

```
mysql> select dayname('2014-11-14');
+-----------------------+
| dayname('2014-11-14') |
+-----------------------+
| Friday                |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, your query will become:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(DT.ds), DT.ds
FROM dateTable DT
WHERE DT.ds = '2014-11-14'
LIMIT 1
```