# Grails - Retrieving data with grouping and summing up of several elements in the domain

Tags: sql, grails, grouping

Apologies for the title, I'm unsure of how to say it precisely.

Given this domain:

```
class PurchaseLog{

    Date dateCreated
    Date logDate // Specific day of log; not necessarily the day it was created
    Branch branch

    static hasMany = [itemCount: ItemCount]
}
```

and:

```
class ItemCount {

    Item item
    Long count

    static belongsTo = [purchaseLog : PurchaseLog]
}
```

The system's supposed to fetch the purchase log (how many of each item was purchased) by day or by week. It creates the logs for each day given the transactions from each branch.

Fetching the inventory logs would be easy for daily, however, the system should consolidate the counts of the items over the week to create the weekly log. I've been trying using SQL, joining the `ItemCount` table with the `PurchaseLog` tables before grouping them and consolidating the item count of each item (getting sum of the counts in each day per item).

Here is the SQL query I've been trying to use:

```
WITH purchase_log_list AS (SELECT pl.log_date, ic.item_id, ic.count, pl.branch_id FROM purchase_log AS pl LEFT JOIN item_count AS ic ON pl.id = ic.purchase_log_id ) 
SELECT item_id, SUM(count) AS countPerWeek, extract(YEAR FROM log_date) as year_group, extract(WEEK FROM log_date) as week_group FROM purchase_log_list WHERE branch_id = :branch_id GROUP BY year_group, week_group, item_id ORDER BY year_group, week_group
```

It is still not working as expected, and I've been working on this for several days. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Seems `ItemCount` belong to `InventoryLog`, is it correct? Or it should be `PurchaseLog`

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to rename that one to PurchaseLog. It's not the actual model, but very similar to what I'm actually programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HQL` for that. `HQL` has several date/time related functions like `day`, `dayofweek` `month`, `year` etc. You can use these functions together with group by for achieving what you want. For example if want the sum of items grouped by week in respect to `PurchaLog.logDate`

```
    //Assuming Item has a name property   
    def logs = ItemCount.executeQuery("select item.name, purchaseLog.logDate, sum(count) from ItemCount group by item.name, dayofweek(purchaseLog.logDate)")
```

**Note1:** This will return a list of list, not a list of `ItemCount`.

**Note2:** Whenever you use `aggregate` function in your selected columns you have to explicitly mention the field names you want in your query and the field type can not be of other domains. Like if you want to get the `Item` from `ItemCount` you need to mention the field name of `Item` like `select item.name ...`. You cannot just mention `select item ...`.

Here is the link to [HQL Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) and [Grails executeQuery](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html). However I could not find `dayofweek` in HQL Doc. But it is supported by HQL and I have used it. Here is an SO post mentioning this [can we group by day of the week using hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222370/can-we-group-by-day-of-the-week-using-hibernate)

Comment: While the HQL did not work for my program,  querying from ItemCount instead of the PurchaseLog did help solve my problem. Thanks!